# Debug assertion failed, string subscript out of range

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to write a function that takes data from a list box, retrieves the account name, and then uses SQL to change the account type. However, for some reason, this code works fine when the list box item contains 'fdsa\t\tdungeon master' but not 'asdf\t\tuser`. In later testing it failed with 'auser\t\tuser'. The message box function indicates that the correct data is being retrieved. What could possible be causing this?

```
void ChangeAccountType(HWND hwnd, std::string NewType)
{
using namespace std;
string strQuery;
string strAccountName;
string strBuffer;
int nIndex = SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_LIST1), LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_LIST1), LB_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)nIndex, (LPARAM)strBuffer.c_str());
MessageBox(hwnd, strBuffer.c_str(), "", NULL);
for(int iii = 0; strBuffer[iii] != '\t'; iii++)
{
    strAccountName += strBuffer[iii];
};
strQuery = "UPDATE account SET `account type` = \"" + NewType + "\" WHERE `User Name` = \"" + strAccountName + "\"";
}
```

The error seems to occur somewhere within the for loop, as the message box just above it works perfectly. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I take it you are 100% sure the string has a TAB in it?

Comment: Yes, the strings submitted to the listbox are in the form "username + \t\t + accounttype", and the listbox displays them correctly

Comment: I can not see any place where you set `strBuffer` to anything, did you maybe forgot some code?

Comment: No one is going to bring up that using `std::string::c_str()` as the `LPARAM~ to `LB_GETTEXT` is _not at all good_?  If you're not using `C++11` you are using undefined behavior at this point.  Even with `C++11`, don't do _this_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string strBuffer` is an empty string, with size `0`, and there is nothing in your code that changes that before you try to access `strBuffer[iii]`, with `iii` equal `0`. This returns a reference to a value initialized `char`, i.e. the  null termination character. Next time around, you access position `1`, which is out of bounds and hence undefined behaviour.

My suspicion is that you are tampering with the string's internal `char` array data, leading to undefined behaviour. Presumably one or more of the functions you pass the [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to attempts to modify it. This in itself leads to undefined behaviour. You cannot use an `std::string`'s [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) as a writeable char buffer.

from **21.4.7.1 [string.accessors]**, `const charT* c_str() const noexcept` and `const charT* data() const noexcept`:

> *Requires*: The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array.

Comment: So why does it work fine when I use the 'fdsa\t\tdungeonmaster' value? And that's why I started using +=, as it failed every time using strAccountName[iii]. And if so, how would I go about getting the first part of the string?

Comment: @MatsPetersson the tab doesn't matter, the access to `strBuffer[0]` on an empty string happens first.

Comment: Why is strBuffer[0] an empty string, it should contain 'a'? The 'a' is shown in the message box before the for loop

Comment: Doh, yes, the loop is skipping tabs, not ending on tabs, sorry.

Comment: @RT_34 I can only imagine you are getting undefined behaviour. You don't legally set the contents of the string to anything, at least not in the code you have shown.

Comment: How does it skip the tabs? They're definitely there, and it works for the aforementioned value?

Comment: @RT_34 undefined behaviour. Anything could happen.

Comment: OK, thanks very much. Still doesn't make much sense to me why it would break so specifically, but it works fine if I switch to a char[50], so the problem is essentially resolved.

Comment: You _should not_ be using `std::string::c_str()` when you need a string buffer that you need to modify.  Doing so prior to `C++11` is undefined behavior, and doing so in `C++11` is _just bad practice_.

Comment: @Chad I am curious, how can it be made to *not* be UB in C++11?

Comment: In `C++11`, `std::string::c_str()` returns a pointer to the internal array used by the string object, and is simply a `const` version of `std::string::data()`.  Modifying it is bad practice (since it's const), but not as bad as it once was, I suppose.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Comment: @Chad I checked in C++11 and it looks like UB.